# How to Update a column in all rows of a table based on a function call with existing value in that same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my user_table called password. 
Now I want to update all password fields in all rows by passing the existing value of password field and update it using the return value from the function. How to achieve it?

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ id ║  username    ║ pwd  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 5636 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  148 ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║  101 ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║  959 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

my function is as follows:

```
function encryptPassword(password)
{
// $new password = my encryption logic here
   return $password;
}
```

How can I update all password cloumn in every row one by one?

Comment: using loop and simple update query you can achieve it

Comment: @AhmedGinani I know it, but is there any way I can update it by calling the function and take the return value in MySQL update query?

Comment: not in one query, no. Select all the rows into a PHP array, loop through, run the encryptPassword function against the password and then UPDATE that row. There's no other way to do it if you need the PHP-specific functionality. MySQL does have some built-in functions to encrypt fields with though, which, depending on your requirements, might remove the need for PHP. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: @ADyson thank you, I need it with PHP, anyhow I will follow your suggested method and update here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ITERATEALLTABLE_PWD`()
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_OLD_PASS varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_NEW_PASS varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_QRY varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_FINISHED INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE VAR_ID INT(11) ;
DECLARE DATABASE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT pwd ,ID  
                FROM TABLENAME;


                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET VAR_FINISHED = 1;

                OPEN DATABASE_CURSOR;
                GET_NEXTRECORD: LOOP

                        FETCH DATABASE_CURSOR INTO VAR_OLD_PASS,VAR_ID;

                           IF VAR_FINISHED = 1 THEN 
                        LEAVE GET_NEXTRECORD;
                        END IF;

                            SET VAR_NEW_PASS =CONCAT(VAR_OLD_PASS,'ABC'); <-------Here you have to implement your crypto operation!>
                            SET @VAR_QRY = CONCAT("UPDATE TABLENAME SET PWD=" , VAR_NEW_PASS , " WHERE ID = ",VAR_ID);

                            PREPARE stmt FROM @VAR_QRY;
                            EXECUTE stmt;

                END LOOP GET_NEXTRECORD;

                CLOSE DATABASE_CURSOR;

END
```

Try above code;

And make changes accordingly for new password,here i had just appending `ABC` with `OLD PASSWORD`.

Hope this help.

Comment: this will be fine if the crypto can be done entirely in MySQL, but OP is saying that they have a PHP method that they are required to use in order to alter each individual password. So this approach cannot work unfortunately.

Comment: Ohhh that's correct. But they may proceed with `MySQL` alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like:

```
" UPDATE `your_table` SET `pwd` = '$NEW_PASSWORD' 
    WHERE `pwd` = 
        (SELECT `pwd` FROM `table` WHERE `pwd`= '$OLD_PASSWORD')
";
```

that's if you want to use a sql query

---

if you want php

$Query = "SELECT * FROM `your_table`";

assuming you already have a sql db connection ready, and assuming you get the data through `get` command

```
$Results = $DB->query($Query)->get();

// Loop through rows
foreach ($results as $result){
     $ID = $result->id;
     $NEW_PWD = ''; // your pwd logic here
     $DB->query("UPDATE `your_table` SET `pwd` = '$NEW_PWD' WHERE `id` = '$ID'")->execute();
}
```

again i am assuming that you already have your db connection ready using mysql_connect or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

the logic behind it is simple.